# How to add a link to a list in php

Tags: php, html, list, href

Hi I have a Api list that is been generated using php here is the code that is been used to generate the list

```
<html>
    <title> API LIST</title>
    <body>
    <?php
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("api_link");


    $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $output = "<ul>";

    foreach($output['A'] as $schools){
        
        $output .= "<li>".$schools['name']."</li>";
    }
        
    $output .="</ul>";
    
    echo $output;
?>
```

the list is populated successfully but how can i add a link to the list so that when a user click on one of the items it opens a particular linked page here are the ways i have tried

```
$output .= "<li <a href="www.google.com/name"></a>".$schools['name']."</li>";
```

```
$output .= "<li>".$schools['name']. <a href="www.google.com/name"></a>"</li>";
```

```
$output .= "<li>".$schools['name']."<a href="www.google.com/name"></a></li>";
```

I don't know where or how to add the **a href** code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need some changes in your code.You can try for

```
$output .= '<a href=https://www.google.com'.$schools['name'].'><li>'.$schools['name'].'</li></a>';
```

As per the comments you can use `.` to concatenate(join) the `string` and `variable` in php.

Comment: Thanks worked as expected it opens up to a link but how can it specify the value as per the list value that is something like `$output .= '<li><a href="www.google.com/+""+.$schools['name'].">'.$schools['name'].'</a></li>';` to make each list open a specific link based on the value of the list selected in other words how to append the link together with the list value that is www.google.com + $schools['name']

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$output .= '<li><a href="www.google.com/name">'.$schools['name'].'</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thanks worked as expected it opens up to a link but how can it specify the value as per the list value that is something like `$output .= '<li><a href="www.google.com/+""+.$schools['name'].">'.$schools['name'].'</a></li>';` to make each list open a specific link based on the value of the list selected in other words how to append the link together with the list value that is www.google.com + $schools['name']